# How to take user input into express router (after it has been loaded)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router

I have:

An app.js which uses the routes (index.js)

An index.js which is where my GET SQL Data is performed initially

An index.pug which has a form to take the input, which includes table.js

The table.js, when the document is ready, gets the value of the user input and stores it as a variable.

Now, I want to take the

```
var userinput
```

and use that in the GET SQL Data in the index.js AFTER everything has loaded of course. It will initially GET a default query. I then need it to take an SQL query which includes the userinput.

But I can't think how to do this because the index.js loads before the table.js, and regardless it needs to load the default data. Currently I can't retrieve the variable in table.js in index.js

Answer (score 0):

In table.js, create an object and set userinput on that object every time it changes.  Export that object using mofule.export.

In index.js require table.js and assign it to a variable.  Now you can access userinput on that variable and it will be whatever you set in table.js.